# Howto go to beginning of line in tmux after remapping prefix to CTRL+A?

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux

following the suggestion in this Archlinux wiki, in the [page about tmux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux) I remapped the command key prefix to `C-a`, to mimic GNU screen and to have something easier on the keyboard than `C-b`. So my .tmux.conf became this:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
```

However, while in screen it was possible to use `C-a a` to jump to the beginning of line, this does not work any more in tmux. As a sidenote, I'm using iTerm2 without the tmux integration.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: remap caps lock to ctrl. Change your life.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You need to tell *tmux* that Prefix+`a` should send the prefix key to the program running in the current pane:

```
bind a send-prefix
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, I had to do this:

```
bind-key C-a send-key C-a
```

I'm using tmux version `3.3a`