# If I set key bind of C-b to c-a in tmux how can I move the cursor to the beginning of the line?

Tags: tmux

I just move from GNU screen to tmux, in screen when I hit `C-a`, then type `a` again can take me to the beginning of the line, I wonder if I stick with `C-a` in tmux how can I work around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto go to beginning of line in tmux after remapping prefix to CTRL+A?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684115/howto-go-to-beginning-of-line-in-tmux-after-remapping-prefix-to-ctrla)

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen Thanks for point out this existing question, It also helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto go to beginning of line in tmux after remapping prefix to CTRL+A?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684115/howto-go-to-beginning-of-line-in-tmux-after-remapping-prefix-to-ctrla)

Comment: [OPINION] While ctrl-a is undoubtedly easier to type on 'qwerty' keyboards than ctrl-b, I generally discourage people from customizing unix tools this way.  If all you did was change tmux's  'prefix' key, it wouldn't be so bad.  But often people aren't content to stop there, and they end up with such a severely customized tmux that they will be out of sorts if ever asked to use someone else's machine that follows the default behaviors.
The best practice is, I feel, to adopt what standards already exist, and save customizations for your own extensions to functionality.

Comment: [ANOTHER OPINION] I suggest to use the `Ctrl-j` prefix for any terminal multiplexer since in both Emacs and Vim behave like the Enter key (as long as your Enter key works you should be fine); also `j` is in your home row; also the left `Ctrl` is usually closer than the right `Ctrl` so `Ctrl-j` it's a fast combination; also `j` looks like a hook.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

As you know, `C-b` is the default prefix in `tmux`. `C-b C-b` is used to send an actual `C-b` character to the terminal. If you switch the prefix to `C-a`, you just need to rebind some keys to update which one sends the `send-prefix` command.

For your `.tmux.conf`:

```
# You probably already put this in
set prefix C-a

unbind-key C-b
bind-key C-a send-prefix
```

Comment: How to move the curser move the beginning of the line ?

Comment: After those keybindings are in place, `C-a C-a`. You can also add `bind-key a send-prefix` to keep the screen-like `C-a a` sequence.

Comment: Really could you show me the code? I know `bind-key C-a last-window` but I can't find `begin-of-line` in the man page of tmux

Comment: The point of `send-prefix` is that it sends the prefix key on to the shell. `tmux` doesn't move the cursor to the beginning of the line; `bash` does it (via `readline`) when it receives `C-a`. Trust me, the above code is what you want in your `.tmux.conf`.

Comment: How stupid I am, I didn't completely quite the tmux session after change the configuration file, now it works thanks a lot !

Comment: you can also do a `C-a :source ~/.tmux.conf` to reload the conf file without quiting your tmux session.

Comment: Or if you change your .tmux.conf settings a lot, you can rebind r (or any other key) to reload the configuration file, by adding these 2 lines to `~/.tmux.conf` file: `unbind r` and `bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf; display "~/.tmux.conf Reloaded"`

Answer (score 93):

Maybe its an issue about the version I am using, but if the above code does not work for you, try this:

```
set -g prefix C-a
unbind-key C-b
bind-key C-a send-prefix
```

Comment: Thanks, the `-g` is certainly required on my Ubuntu install, perhaps the op should confirm that the accepted answer still works for him?

Comment: seems like the -g option is also required for mac

Comment: Works for me on mac without the `-g` :|

Comment: The global mean "all sessions" - I had the same issue, with one session updated but the other not. -g saves the day.

Comment: -g is required on "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows"

Comment: I needed `-g` using fish on an Ubuntu derivative

Comment: Confirmed that on my Debian 9 and tmux version 2.3. Thanks.